# Bidirectional touch swipe slider for both horizontal and vertical

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, slide, swipe

There are many JavaScript or CSS touch swipe sliders out there but all of them seem to only allow either vertical or horizontal swipe of a slide.  Is there anything out there that allows both on one slide, so I can swipe horizontally and vertically on one slide?

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you find any slider with this behavior?

Comment: @briler I immediately thought of the [idangero.us swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/), but that was already mentioned in an answer. Could you describe what it is that you need in a little more detail? I'm not able to conceptualize what you are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, but it looks darn close:

iDangero.us Swiper.

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

Allows vertical swping boxes within another horizontal carousel/slider. I've been looking for the same thing for awhile, and this is the closest plugin I've found to what I'm looking for. A little hacking/manipulation could probably make it do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I started with but it only supports either/or not both horizontal and vertical swipe on one slide.

Comment: nice ! It would've had touch behaviors (tap, double tap, etc…), it would have absolutely perfect !

Answer (score 2):

Here is an Easy Way of clreating horizontal and vertical slider

```
<script>
function MM_effectSlide1(targetElement, duration, to, from, slide, toggle)
{
    Spry.Effect.DoSlide(targetElement, {duration: duration, to: to, from: from, horizontal: true, toggle: true});
} 
function MM_effectSlide2(targetElement, duration, to, from, slide, toggle)
{
    Spry.Effect.DoSlide(targetElement, {duration: duration, to: to, from: from, horizontal: false, toggle: true});
}
</script>

<body>
    <div id="socialmedia" class="socialcontainer" onclick="MM_effectSlide1('socialmedia', 1000, '100%', '11%', true, true)"></div>
```

If you look at the Code the only code that should be changed is the MM_effectSlide1, 2, 3, and so forth

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) to have swipes exactly as you describe, as shown on [this demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage).

The only issue I have with fullPage.js is the lack of 1:1 touch movement. So instead of the swipe being controlled as long as you have your finger on the screen, the script has a configurable variable that says once a threshold swipe of X percent of the screen height/width has been met. This works, but doesn't feel nearly as nice as something like [RoyalSlider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) which does have 1:1 touch movement; so if you swipe only 49% of the way you remain on the same section. That said fullPage.js has great support (IE8+) and is updated regularly.

Ideally I'd like fullPage.js to [have 1:1 touch movement](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/278), the author is open to pull requests but for now my knowledge of javascript is too basic to implement something like this.

An option I am considering at the moment is using two sliders in combination with each other. I am going to use [RoyalSlider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) for the left and right swipes (so you get the nice 1:1 touch) and fullPage.js for the vertical up down effect.